# How to avoid displaying everthing in console in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, performance, variables, display

When I declare a variable in matlab or anything else, matlab displays it, thereby slowing the processes.
For example if I declare a variable like this: `x= 1:0.01:10000`, Matlab displays it on the screen. I don't want to print these variables.

Answer (score 5):

You have to put a semicolon `;` behind your declarations and function calls that include a return.

```
A = zeros(3,4); %Semicolon supresses console output
```